# How to map one class variable to two form fields in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I wold like to use Symfony 2.8 to create a form for data class, e.g. `Task` as used in the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html).

My `Task` class uses an integer field `flags` to store a collection different bool values. For example the value of `is completed` is stored as the first bit and `is urgent` as the second bit:

- Task is **not** completed and **not** urgent --> flags = 0
- Task is completed and **not** urgent --> flags = 1
- Task is **not** completed and urgent --> flags = 2
- Task is completed and urgent --> flags = 3
- ...

**The problem:** How can this single class field be mapped to two different form fields and back?

```
$builder
    // map first bit to checkbox
    ->add('is_complete', CheckboxType::class, array(
            ...
        )
    )
    // map second bit to selection box "normal"/"urgent"
    ->add('is_urgend', ChoiceType::class, array(
            ...
        )
    )
    ...
```

What is the correct solution to solve this? Can this be handled by a **Data Transformers**? As far as I know, a transformer can translate a field of one to type to another type, but not one field to two fields. Is that correct?

The only solution I found so far, is to create a wrapper class `TaskWrapper` which does not use flags but offers different bool fields for the each flag value. This class could than be passed to the form instead of the original `Task` class. Once the form is submitted the returned wrapper object could than be manually translated back to a `Task` object.

This would work, but it is not a clean solution. Is this the way to go or is there a better solution using Symfony tools?

Comment: Why would'nt you store two different booleans? One for `completed` and the other one for `urgent`?

Comment: This is just an example, the real entity class uses the `flags` field to store even more values. Additionally it is bound to some external API I cannot change. Thus using flags really does make sense in this case.

Comment: I would store the flags as separate attributes and write a coder/decoder class to talk to the external API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for multiple boolean properties. It is easier at form-level and at persistence-level.

If you require to use that `$flags` property and you are using Doctrine, you can take use of the multiple boolean properties without mapping them. When submitting a form the fields are mapped directly to the entity properties except for those with `mapped = false`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped

Then implement an eventlistener for events `prePersist` and `preUpdate` that set the `flags` property before creating/updating the Task:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

For keeping consistency you can set the `$urgent` and `$complete` property values through `setFlags()`, since it will only be called either manually or when loading the entity.